# Como tirar os zeros do tempo?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, conversão-de-tipo, conversão

Estou utilizando um Label para receber o tempo de um vídeo. O tempo que recebo do vídeo é um `double` que vem em milissegundos, por exemplo: 1555 = 1.555 seg. 
Quando converto para `TimeSpan`o Label aparece da seguinte forma: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código que estou usando é:

```
        dt = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Player.input.time);
        Cronometro.Text = dt.ToString();
```

Aqueles zeros que aparecem depois dos números não deveriam estar ali. Era pra ser **00:00:03.431**
Utilizo um Windows Form.

Answer (score 1):

Se utilizar este codigo irá "truncar" o valor a 3 casas decimais, no entanto pode perder os ":"

```
Cronometro.Text = dt.tostring("N3");
```

Comment: Não funcionou, migo.

Comment: experimente o que atualizei

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode utilizar as função **substring** para isso isso.

Neste caso você pegaria HH:MM:SS:MS, o que daria 11 caracteres(considerando os :), ou seja, você pegaria os caracteres da posição 0 até a posição 11.

```
//cria uma variável string cujo conteúdo vem de dt(sua variável que guarda o     tempo)
string tempo = dt.ToString()
// Obtém 11 caracteres a partir da posição 0 (primeiro caracter)
Cronometro.Text = tempo.Substring(0, 11);
```